# Training with code scripts to achieve a specified goal?

Tags: machine-learning, training

I am quite new to machine learning and therefore need to ask if some ideas might be possible.

Imagine an application that is managing the state of an `Actor` by scripts. The timed iteration in the following is called a `tick`.

The application is using a script that defines *what* should happen to an actor every tick.

example script:

```
logic body_system {
    actors::state(hydration).minus(5);
    actors[state.hydration < 30]::state(health).minus(1);
}

logic drink {
    actors[state.hydration < 90]::state(hydration).plus(2);
}
```

So every `tick` the `body_system` and the `drink` logic is called. The first one will decrease the `hydration` state while the `drink` logic wants to prevent death by increasing the `hydration` state.

However as you might have seen the `drink` logic is only increasing by `2` while `body_system` is decreasing `hydration` by 5.
In the long term the `Actor` will die with these scripts.
The state of the actor is checked after every `tick`. If `state.health <= 0` the `Actor` is considered dead.

---

Now since I have an input of data (the scripts) and a way to check the `true` and `false` required state (the death of an `Actor`) is it possible to create a training model by this? I know I need a large set of different scripts with different outcomes. But given that - is it possible to train a machine towards the goal to **generate** a very good script that might keep the `Actor` alive for a long time?

I just want to figure out if I understand the concepts or better said the requirements to training data in the context of machine learning.

Comment: This looks like a problem where applying reinforcement learning would make sense.

Comment: @noe is this something that can be done using Jupyter Notebooks and such?

Comment: Sure, but reinforcement learning is normally difficult to get right and your problem does not seem easy to formulate. Certainly not something to do in a casual way taking code from some blog post.

Comment: Well ok at least I have a direction to educate myself. Just ordered me a book about reinforcement learning :) thanks for that